Disconnecting the specified IP
I have a server on port 10000, and devices connect to it. How can I disable the specified device by his IP address? There may be several device IP addresses on the port, and need to disable the specified one.
I tried to do it through the socket library in Python, but it requires a connection to a port that is already occupied by the server therefore, the code below does not work for me.
def drop_connections(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, port))
        s.close()
        print(f"Connection to {ip}:{port} closed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while closing connection: {e}")


You're trying to close a socket from a program other than the one that opened it?

Yes, not from that program.

There's no standard way to do this. Only the process that opened the socket can normally close it.

you can google "Linux forcibly close socket by ip address" and find some possible commands.

I've tried tools like "cutter" "tcpkill" and they don't work. These are the only solutions that could work for me, but they don't work. Are there any other ideas on how to break the connection? If you need more details, then I have a shadowsocks server on a certain port, and I'm trying to limit the number of connections to it, so I need to sort out the extra ones somehow. For example, the limit is "2 devices", that is, the third device should not connect. I have written a program that identifies this "superfluous device". I have his IP address, but I do not know how to disable it.

This is usually something that would be configured in the server software itself, not something you do outside the application.

Anyway, [unix.se] would be the place to ask.

That's the point, there's no such thing, and I'm trying to find a solution :(

That's the point, there isn't really a solution. There's no API for killing arbitrary connections.
